# Is it possible to compile a JS app + the NodeJS interpreter into a single executable?

Tags: javascript, compilation, distribution, node.js

Is it possible to compile a JS application and the NodeJS interpreter into a single executable for distribution?

Comment: Check out: http://www.appcelerator.com/ if you want to develop executables using JS, HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thanks @BGerrissen, but it's actually a server-side node.js app that's already running which I'd like to "safely" distribute to a client's servers.

Comment: Don't think nodejs tooling is that far yet alas. Been looking around and seeing lots of manual configurations. All involve installing nodejs and then deploying code using git or whatnot.

Answer (score 6):

you need a linux box with git and python, then ugly solution:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
$ cd node
$ vim src/node.js    # add your code to end before "process.loop();"
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ node
```

Comment: Ugly indeed. I think you'd better overwrite the `if (process.argv[1]) {...module.runMain()` part in `src/node.js`, and load your code as a root module instead of inserting it verbatim. I haven't tested though.

Comment: the idea was guide digitala to read the nodejs source code :)

Comment: @Lauri, will this compile the JS to bytecode or will it store the code as a string in memory to be executed on run time?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to compile a JS application and the NodeJS interpreter into a single executable for distribution?

This might sound obvious, but here's my take on it.

A "single executable for distribution" sounds a lot like an installer...

An installer would contain or be able to fetch online your js scripts and a compiled node.js. It would unpack everything and create a script in /etc/init.d/ to start and stop the server.

If all your clients are on the same distro (e.g. Debian), I'd just make a package for the appropriate packaging tool (e.g. apt) and let the package tool handle everything.

It the clients all have different distros, you could look into [autopackage](http://www.autopackage.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to execute javascript, you might be able to create a simple C or C++ wrapper program which would spawn an interpreter and evaluate your JS. If you want a single file, the js source could be included as a string constant.

When you compiled the wrapper program, you'd want to [statically link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) it to node and the rest of its dependency tree.  Rather than depending on shared libraries on the system, static linking will copy the routines your project depends on into the compiled binary.

How you do this will depend on your environment